# Rails schema not changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I'm trying to change a column called "description" in my table called "posts" to a .text rather than a .string so I can avoid getting errors for the value being too long.

I generated a new migration and ran rake db:migrate after having this:

```
class ChangePostsFormatInMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    change_column :posts, :description, :text, :limit => nil
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :posts, :description, :string
  end
end
```

But the schema file doesn't show any changes and my column won't change. Am I missing something?

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140125221803) do 
  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string "description" 
    t.datetime "created_at" 
    t.datetime "updated_at" 
    t.integer "user_id" 
    t.string "image_file_name" 
    t.string "image_content_type" 
    t.integer "image_file_size" 
    t.datetime "image_updated_at" 
    t.string "title" 
    t.string "image" 
  end
end
```

Comment: hi! could you try it without the :options :limit=> nil ?

Comment: also which version of rails are you using

Comment: I'm using rails 4.0 and I tried taking out the limit option and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: could you provide some info? what db are you using? could you provide your schema dump before/after `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Rails4 does support up and down methods. I've used it to alter another table and that one works. As far as the db, where can I find that? (Sorry I'm still trying to teach myself). The schema isn't changing after rake db:migrate.

Comment: ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140125221803) do

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "image"
  end

Comment: up/down are not class methods. Drop the `self.`

Comment: hmm, dropping the self didn't work either...

Comment: Just to confirm you are looking at the schema for the `development` DB and not the `test` DB. You will need to run `rake db:test:prepare` to get any changes to also happen to the `test` DB.

Comment: Does `rake db:migrat:status` show the migration as pending or complete? Maybe if you roll back a few migrations and re-migrate?

Comment: how do i roll back migrations?

Comment: FWIW, I was able to reproduce this locally. Very strange.

Comment: Yes! I don't get this problem on my local host but only on heroku... Have no idea why it's not working.